# Match objects between SharePoint lists and update to show match

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am looking to match details of users from 1 environment to another. The user details are added to different SharePoint lists manually, uploaded and automatic additions. The columns I am attempting to match with are givenname, surname and displayname. In some cases, only the display name is provided.
I am trying to get the email address, alias and memberships of the user objects, match them to existing users and collect the additions and mark them as matched or unmatched.

Source list Example

[image]

Destination list Example

[image]

I have been using excel with a xlookup to accomplish this task. I am looking to automate this task using power automate. I can get all the data from both lists using a odata filter that only looks for objects with a "unmatched" status. I have been able to do matching with smaller lists but that is using nested "Apply to each" actions and when the lists become large, the actions time out or I will hit view limits.

I believe there is a method to do that, but I cannot locate it. I have been able to match smaller lists with all the same data points, but I cannot update the main list with the items from the matched object.
I know there are similar questions but those are looking for scripting languages that I do not use.
I am also open to a efficient PowerShell option. I have a method but it uses nested foreach loops so I can come up with partial matches. I have tried using pnp.powershell module but this now has a requirement of PowerShell v7 which I currently cannot utilize for this task.
Any thoughtful suggestions are appreciated. I am proficient with PowerShell, but not an expert.

Comment: Do you have a premium licence? There is a connector that may be able to help.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have a premium license. What is the connector called?